# Existence and Proof of the Limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Determine if this sequence has a limit, and if it does prove that the stated value is actually the limit. How would I do this using the analytical $\varepsilon$ and $N$ argument? The sequence is the following,

$$a_n = \frac{\sin(n^2-n)}{n}$$

Any solutions or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\left|\sin x\right|\leq 1$

Comment: Hint: before you start with the $\varepsilon$ and $N$ argument you need to be reasonably sure you know what the limit is.  What do you think it is?

Comment: I believe the limit to be zero.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

- Given any $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N$ such that $N > \frac1\epsilon$.
- Use the fact that for $n > N$,
  $$
  \left|a_n - 0\right| = \frac{\left|\sin(n^2 - n)\right|}{n} \le \frac{1}{n} \le \frac{1}{N} < \cdots
  $$